# Check if it is the last element in an array inside map() function

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of strings and I want to print them on different lines.

I'm using `<hr />` for this but as it is now in my code, it will put another break after the last string, fact that I want to avoid. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
return myArray.map((text, index) => (
    <span key={index}>
        {myArray[index]}
        {<hr />}
    </span>
));
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can check if its last element by checking if there is next element `arr[i + 1]`

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var html = arr.map(function(e, i) {
  return `<span key="${i}">${e}</span>${arr[i+1] ? '<hr>' : ''}` 
})

document.body.innerHTML += html.join('')
```

Comment: I've got one small improvement: `<span key="${i}"...` (`${i}` instead of `${e}`).

Comment: Couldn't be simpler! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
myArray.map((text, index, {length}) => (
  /* ... your code ... */
  if(index + 1 === length){ //last element

  }
));
//{length} === myArray.length; third argument is an array
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them in a pragraph and not in a span

```
return myArray.map((text, index) => (
    <p key={index}>
        {text}
    </p>
));
```

Comment: it is quite a simple and straightforward solution but I also need <hr /> tag. or something to look like a horizontal line between the strings

Comment: Can you add some CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check upon iterated `index`,  `if(index < (myArray.length-1))` :

```
return myArray.map((text, index) => (
    <span key={index}>
        {myArray[index]}
        if(index < (myArray.length-1))
          {<hr />}
    </span>
));
```